# To compute digits of Integer

Tags: java

This program is for computing the digits of an integer. So there is chances to enter the input by user may string("raju" whatever it may be), number(12334), combination(string & number i.e, 234dsd) and nothing(he doesn't enter anything), isn't it? There might be another chances too I don't know(If there is mention it here).Try out with various inputs and the problems here are when I entered number and nothing. If input is number "result not coming" cmd prompt not continuing further and input is nothing(not entered) *if* statement is not executing. when the cmd prompt goes like that?

```
//computing digits of integer.
import java.util.Scanner;
 class Main
 {
 public static void main (String w[]) 
 {
    Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter a number");
    String g=s.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Entered value is"+g);
    if(g==null)
    {
        System.out.println("Enter atleast one number");
    }
    else
    {
    try
    {
            int st=Integer.parseInt(g); 
            int sum=0;      
            while(st>=0)
            {
                int value=st%10;
                st=st/10;           
                sum=value+sum;
            }
            System.out.println("the sum of digits: "+sum);

    }catch (NumberFormatException nfe)
    {
        System.err.println("Invalid input. Enter only number...");
    }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: I never used this one.. So please understand the entire program code is above. Not a code in colored.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to understand you are asking here, but if you are asking you code is not trying again when the user inputs invalid input, the answer is that it is because your code has no loop to do that.

Repetition of something (in this case, the task of asking for input) generally requires a loop of some kind.

If you indented your code properly, this would probably be more obvious to you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
//computing digits of integer.
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String w[]) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a number");
        String g = s.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Entered value is " + g);
        try {
            int st = Integer.parseInt(g);
            int sum = 0;
            while (st > 0) {
                int value = st % 10;
                st = st / 10;
                sum = value + sum;
            }
            System.out.println("the sum of digits: " + sum);
        } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
            System.err.println("Invalid input. Enter only number...");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: nice but if I pass nothing it should show another message. Try it out for that purpose.

Answer (score 0):

None of the answers so far explicitly mentioned the problem: There is an endless loop here:

```
        int st=Integer.parseInt(g); 
        int sum=0;      
        while(st>=0)
        {
            int value=st%10;
            st=st/10;           
            sum=value+sum;
        }
```

because `st` never becomes negative when you start with a positive value.